# Swift UIDocumentInteractionController doesn't use device language

Tags: ios, swift, uialertcontroller, uidocumentinteraction, uidocument

I'm trying to delegate the opening of a file my app created to an other app using the UIDocumentInteractionController within an UIAlertAction like this:

```
// variable in the class
var documentController:UIDocumentInteractionController!

// the alertAction
let okAction = UIAlertAction(title: "Öffnen", style: .default, handler: { (_) in
            self.documentController = UIDocumentInteractionController(url: filePath)
            self.documentController.presentOpenInMenu(from: self.view.frame, in: self.view, animated: true)
        })
```

The Problem is that the UIDocumentInteractionController is always presented in english even though the device-language is something different.
Did I miss something?
Where can I change the language for the UIDocumentInteractionController?

Comment: What do you mean? The cancel button it is always in English?

Comment: Does your app support localizations other than English?

Comment: @LeoDabus Yes the cancel-Button is always in english and the the texts for the different apps are in english too. For example "Add to Notes"

Comment: Well for me here only the cancel button it is not localized

Comment: @rmaddy My app is completly german. Do I have to change something in Xcode or Project-Settings for that?

Comment: @LeoDabus thats strange

Comment: @rmaddy Even my English only app gets localized except the cancel button

Comment: @LarsGvB In Xcode, select your project and look at the Info tab (for the project, not the target). What is shown under Localizations?

Comment: @rmaddy It says "English - Development Language". Should I change that? And if so, how do I do that?

Comment: @LarsGvB See https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bios%5D+change+development+language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rmaddy comment to change the Developement-Language worked. Now everything in the UIDocumentInteractionController is displayed in german.